# How to get CMB2 to show a single image at a specific size

Tags: plugins, images

Trying to get the CMB2 plugin to display an image at the WP default medium size on the page. I can get it to display an image but that image could be any size the user wants I'd rather it was cropped to a fixed size.

In the functions I have the CMB set up:

```
        add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'cmb2_page' );

        function cmb2_page() {

        $prefix = 'cmb_one_';


        $cmb_two->add_field( array(
          'name'          => __( 'Image Loader', 'cmb2' ),
          'desc'          => 'Upload an image or enter an URL.',
          'id'            => $prefix . 'image_two',
          'type'          => 'file',
            'options' => array(
                'url' => true,
            ),
            'text'    => array(
                'add_upload_file_text' => 'Add Image' 
            ),
            'query_args' => array(
                'type' => array(
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png',
                ),
            ),
            'preview_size' => 'medium', // Image size to use when previewing in the admin.
           ) );

        }
```

on the page I have:

```
      <?php
          echo $image_two = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cmb_one_image_two', 1 ), 'medium' );
      ?>
```

and I can get the image to show if I just use:

```
      <?php
          echo  '<img src="'. $image_two .'"  alt="image dis">';
      ?>
```

But if I do that there's no way to control the image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ID of the attachment, and then use that to get whichever size you need.

https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#file

> A file uploader. By default it will store the file url and allow
>   either attachments or URLs. **This field type will also store the
>   attachment ID (useful for getting different image sizes). It will
>   store it in $id . '_id'**, so if your field id is wiki_test_image the ID
>   is stored in wiki_test_image_id. You can also limit it to only
>   allowing attachments (can't manually type in a URL), which is also
>   useful if you plan to use the attachment ID. The example shows its
>   default values, with possible values commented inline.

```
wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cmb_one_image_two_id', 1 ), 'medium' );
```

if you want to crop it to a different size:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cmb_one_image_two_id', 1 ), 'different_size' );
```

and in `functions.php` use [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

```
add_image_size( 'different_size', 220, 180 );
```